# Prove transitivity $a \leq b$, $b \leq c \implies a \leq c$ by structural induction

Tags: solution-verification, induction

I want to prove the following by structural induction: $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N} : a \leq b$, $b \leq c \implies a \leq c$

$\mathbb{N}$ is defined inductively as follows:

**Basis**: $0 \in \mathbb{N}$

**Ind**: If $ n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $s(N) \in \mathbb{N}$ (successor)

$\leq$ is defined inductively as follows:

**Basis**: $(0,n) \in \; \leq$ , for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

**Ind**: if $(m,n) \in \; \leq$ then $(s(m),s(n)) \in \; \leq$.

I am given two hints:

**(1)**: For each $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, if $s(m) \leq n$ then $n=s(n')$ for some $n' \in \mathbb{N}$.

**(2)**: For each $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, if $s(m) \leq s(n)$ then $m \leq n$.

I am a bit confused about what to do induction on to prove the claim.
My current proof looks like this:

Proof by structural induction on $\leq$, precisely a and c.

**Basis** ($a=0$, see Basis of $\leq$): $0 \leq c$ , by Basis $\leq$.

**Ind. Step:** Show: $s(a') \leq b, b \leq s(c') \implies s(a') \leq s(c')$

**I.H.:** $a' \leq b', b' \leq c' \implies a' \leq c'$

$s(a') \leq b \implies s(a') \leq s(b'), b=s(b')$, by **(1)**

$s(a') \leq s(b') \implies a' \leq b'$, by **(2)**

$b \leq s(c') \iff s(b') \leq s(c')$, because $b=s(b')$

$s(b') \leq s(c') \implies b' \leq c'$, by **(2)**

$a' \leq b',b' \leq c' \implies a' \leq c'$, by **I.H.**

$a' \leq c' \implies s(a') \leq s(c')$, by Ind. $\leq$

Is it correct to do induction on a and c? Is the proof sufficient to prove the claim? What about b?

How can one decide this in general when doing inductive proofs?

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want induction, IMO it is a little bit more complex. I would suggest induction on $c$, using an additional fact (3): $n \le 0 \to n=0$. (3) is provable considering that if we assume that $n \ne 0$ then $n=s(x)$ for some $x$ and thus $s(x) \le 0$. From (1) it follows that $0=s(y)$ for some $y$, contradicting the axiom for $0$.

Comment: Yes, the task is to do the proof by induction. Otherwise, it would be easier :)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I do not quite get what you are saying. I understand fact (3). I have also used it in the Base case of the proof. But why do you suggest induction on c? And what is the contraction about?

Comment: You are making induction on $a$? If so, the base case $(0 \le b) \land (b \le c) \to (0 \le c)$ is fine. Then assume it holds for $a$ and you must prove that $(s(a) \le b) \land (b \le c) \to (s(a) \le c)$.

Comment: If so, the next step is induction on $c$. Is this what you are doing?

Comment: I am kind of doing it at the same time on a and c at the moment. But I also did it on each of the variables individually as well a couple of days ago. I am still wondering what I have to do induction on to fully prove the claim.
Do you mean I have to do it for a and after that for c?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123613/discussion-between-nick-junior-and-mauro-allegranza).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct way to prove this is to choose the induction property P wisely. The for all quantification for m and n does the trick:

[image: Proof]